# Custom Kernel, access eMMC memory

Tags: linux, kernel

I am building kernels in my company.
Currently we have asurface 3 (non pro) device here and it sould boot with our own kernel and miniroot.
so far it boots up, but doesnt detect the eMMC memory.
IN the future more eMMC devices should be supported so I added a lot of mmc drivers directly into the kernel. We are limited to 90MB miniroot size, so every driver usually is build into the kernel

here's the current mmc config

```
cat kernel/config-x86_64-4.4.11 | grep MMC
# CONFIG_PCI_MMCONFIG is not set
CONFIG_MMC=y
CONFIG_MMC_DEBUG=y
# MMC/SD/SDIO Card Drivers
CONFIG_MMC_BLOCK=m
CONFIG_MMC_BLOCK_MINORS=8
CONFIG_MMC_BLOCK_BOUNCE=y
CONFIG_MMC_TEST=y
# MMC/SD/SDIO Host Controller Drivers
CONFIG_MMC_SDHCI=y
CONFIG_MMC_SDHCI_PCI=y
# CONFIG_MMC_RICOH_MMC is not set
CONFIG_MMC_SDHCI_ACPI=y
CONFIG_MMC_SDHCI_PLTFM=y
CONFIG_MMC_WBSD=y
CONFIG_MMC_TIFM_SD=y
CONFIG_MMC_SDRICOH_CS=y
CONFIG_MMC_CB710=y
CONFIG_MMC_VIA_SDMMC=y
CONFIG_MMC_VUB300=y
CONFIG_MMC_USHC=y
CONFIG_MMC_USDHI6ROL0=y
# CONFIG_MMC_REALTEK_USB is not set
CONFIG_MMC_TOSHIBA_PCI=y
CONFIG_MMC_MTK=y

CONFIG_MMC_SDHCI=y
CONFIG_MMC_SDHCI_PCI=y
CONFIG_MMC_SDHCI_ACPI=y
CONFIG_MMC_SDHCI_PLTFM=y
```

Still the mmcblk device does not show up.
any suggestions on how to make this work? Any modules I might be missing?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Well the Surface 3 Tablet works a little bit different
After adding GPIO kernel modules the eMMC memory got recognized and usable